# An Error occurred while installing bs4 with pipenv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, pipenv

I want to install bs4 on a virtual enviroment, but an error occurred and I dont know why.

I already updated bs4, pip and pipenv.

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PYTEST\temp>pipenv install beautifulsoup4
Installing beautifulsoup4…
Adding beautifulsoup4 to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (06c5f2)…
An error occurred while installing beautifulsoup==3.2.2 --hash=sha256:a04169602bff6e3138b1259dbbf491f5a27f9499dea9a8fbafd48843f9d89970 --hash=sha256:d31413d71f6ca027ff6b06c891b62ee8ff48267ccd969f881d810e5d1fe49565! Will try again.
  ================================ 9/9 - 00:00:05
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1992, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       skip_lock=skip_lock,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting beautifulsoup==3.2.2', '  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/f2/6c9f2f3e696ee6a1fb0e4d7850617e224ed2b0b1e872110abffeca2a09d4/BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:', '     command: \'c:\\users\\acer\\.virtualenvs\\temp-mutvn0yg\\scripts\\python.exe\' -c \'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = \'"\'"\'C:\\\\Users\\\\ACER\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-wjnq523g\\\\beautifulsoup\\\\setup.py\'"\'"\'; __file__=\'"\'"\'C:\\\\Users\\\\ACER\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-wjnq523g\\\\beautifulsoup\\\\setup.py\'"\'"\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'"\'"\'open\'"\'"\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'"\'"\'\\r\\n\'"\'"\', \'"\'"\'\\n\'"\'"\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'"\'"\'exec\'"\'"\'))\' egg_info --egg-base \'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wjnq523g\\beautifulsoup\\pip-egg-info\'', '         cwd: C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wjnq523g\\beautifulsoup\\', '    Complete output (6 lines):', '    Traceback (most recent call last):', '      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>', '      File "C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wjnq523g\\beautifulsoup\\setup.py", line 3', '        "You\'re trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package \'beautifulsoup4\'."', '                                                                                                        ^', '    SyntaxError: invalid syntax', '    ----------------------------------------', 'ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
     ================================ 0/1 - 00:00:02
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is badly formatted but the info is there...

> "You\'re trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package \'beautifulsoup4\'."

Also at the beginning of your trace it clearly states that it is trying to install `beautifulsoup`, apparently because it is in your `Pipfile.lock`. Obviously you want `beautifulsoup4` instead. Just fix this and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

`pipenv` has successfully installed `beautifulsoup4`, as can be seen in the trace:

> Installing beautifulsoup4…
>   Adding beautifulsoup4 to Pipfile's [packages]…
>   Installation Succeeded

The error is happening after, when `pipenv` is trying to complete the installation of previously failed dependencies, in this case `beautifulsoup 3.2.2`. To fix this, you should remove the old version of `beautifulsoup` from your `Pipfile.lock` dependencies by using:

`pipenv uninstall beautifulsoup`

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue, removing "beautifulsoup" from my Pipfile solved it.